# Exception when using `WindowDistance` function with a custom key type from C#

Tags: c#, f#, deedle

When trying to call `WindowDistance` function from Deedle for a series with a custom key type I get `Specified method is not supported.` exception:

```
public static IEnumerable<DateTime> DateRange(
                  DateTime aStart, DateTime aEnd, TimeSpan aOffset)
{
    var current = aStart;
    while (current <= aEnd)
    {
        yield return current;

        current += aOffset;
    }
}

var series =
       DateRange(
           new DateTime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), 
           new DateTime(2017, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), 
           TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
       .Select((i, ind) => KeyValue.Create(new MyKey(i, ind), ind))
       .ToSeries();

Deedle.SeriesModule.WindowDistance(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), series);
```

The key class is defined as follows:

```
class MyKey : IComparable
{
    public DateTimeOffset DateTime { get; }
    public int Index { get; }

    public MyKey(DateTimeOffset aDateTime, int aIndex)
    {
        DateTime = aDateTime;
        Index = aIndex;
    }

    public static TimeSpan operator -(MyKey a, MyKey b)
    {
        return a.DateTime - b.DateTime;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is MyKey mk)
        {
            return DateTime.CompareTo(mk.DateTime);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                $"Unexpected comparison to type: {obj.GetType().Name}");
        }
    }
}
```

It seems that the problem is caused by the `-` operator defined in `MyKey` class.
Similar code written in F# works fine. But the C# code fails even if I use the class `MyKey` written in F#:

```
type MyKey(timeStamp: DateTimeOffset, value) = 

    member this.Timestamp = timeStamp
    member this.Value = value

    interface IComparable with
        member this.CompareTo (x: obj) =
            this.Timestamp.CompareTo((x :?> MyKey).Timestamp)

    static member (-) (a: MyKey, b: MyKey) =
        a.Timestamp - b.Timestamp
```

The call stack for the exception:

```
at Deedle.SeriesModule.WindowDistance@905.Invoke(K skey, K ekey) in C:\code\deedle\src\Deedle\SeriesModule.fs:line 905
at Deedle.Internal.Seq.windowRangesWhile@990.GenerateNext(IEnumerable`1& next) in C:\code\deedle\src\Deedle\Common\Common.fs:line 1001
at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.MoveNextImpl()
at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1.System-Collections-IEnumerator-MoveNext()
at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Internal.IEnumerator.map@74.DoMoveNext(b& )
at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Internal.IEnumerator.MapEnumerator`1.System-Collections-IEnumerator-MoveNext()
at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Internal.IEnumerator.map@74.DoMoveNext(b& )
at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Internal.IEnumerator.MapEnumerator`1.System-Collections-IEnumerator-MoveNext()
at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Internal.IEnumerator.map@74.DoMoveNext(b& )
at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Internal.IEnumerator.MapEnumerator`1.System-Collections-IEnumerator-MoveNext()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.ArrayModule.OfSeq[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Deedle.Indices.Linear.LinearIndexBuilder.Deedle-Indices-IIndexBuilder-Aggregate[K,TNewKey,R](IIndex`1 index, Aggregation`1 aggregation, VectorConstruction vector, FSharpFunc`2 selector) in C:\code\deedle\src\Deedle\Indices\LinearIndex.fs:line 325
at Deedle.Series`2.Aggregate[TNewKey,R](Aggregation`1 aggregation, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 valueSelector) in C:\code\deedle\src\Deedle\Series.fs:line 717
at Deedle.SeriesModule.WindowDistance[D,K,T](D distance, Series`2 series) in C:\code\deedle\src\Deedle\SeriesModule.fs:line 905
```

The inner exception is `null`.

Comment: Please show call stack and inner exceptions (if any).

Comment: I have updated my question with the stack trace.

Comment: Doesn't look like it has anything to do with the custom operator. I would rather look into versions of DLLs, make sure all versions are compatible with each other.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a dll problem. I tried to move different parts of the code between C# and F# modules and the same C# module works fine as long as MyKey and the call to WindowDistance are moved to the F# library which is called from C#